# CkEditor и html

Tags: javascript, html, ckeditor

Пытаюсь добавить нужный html в CkEditor редактор, но ничего не происходит:

```
 var html = '<a rel="group" class="fancybox" href="'+large_url+'">'+
      '<i style="background-image: url('+small_url+')" class="uiMediaThumbImg"></i>'+
        '</a>';

    CKEDITOR.instances.message_text.insertHtml(html, "unfiltered_html");
```

Хотя если в html будет, например, `<p>Какой-то html</p>`, то все отобразиться корректно в редакторе. Видимо, сыпится на куске, где стоит тег `<i>`.

Подскажите, в чем проблема?

Comment: можете поискать в настройках редактора, так указаны разрешенные теги, возможно вам просто стоит разрешить нужный тег...

Answer (score 1):

Нашел решение. Все оказалось просто:
Во всем виноват тег `<i>` Заменил его на `<img>` и все заработало.
Привожу рабочий код:

```
var html = '<a rel="group" class="fancybox" href="'+large_url+'">'+
    '<img src="'+small_url+'" class="uiMediaThumbImg">'+
    '</a>';

CKEDITOR.instances.message_text.insertHtml(html, "unfiltered_html");
```

Comment: если Вы нашли решение, отметьте пожалуйста ответ как решение (зеленая галка под цифрой слева от ответа).

Answer (score 0):

А как-нибудь так не пробовал?

```
var html = '<a rel="group" style="display: block; background-image: url('+small_url+')" class="fancybox uiMediaThumbImg" href="'+large_url+'">'+
    '</a>';
```

Просто предположение для уменьшения кол-ва строк.